# PHP filter_var function returns string instead of boolean

Tags: php, ftp

*Code*

```
<?php
$test = filter_var("ftp://ftp.is.co.za.example.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
var_dump($test);
?>
```

This returns;

> string(46) "ftp://ftp.is.co.za.example.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt"

Instead of boolean.

The problem is,
I need to validate if a string is either URL or S/FTP address.

According to [PHP Doc](http://php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.validate.php) comment that the example above should pass the `filter_var` function. But I can't seem to get it working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It should return a string if it's valid, it only returns a Boolean false if it's invalid..... and your example is valid: `Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol http:// so further validation may be required to determine the URL uses an expected protocol, e.g. ssh:// or mailto:.`

Comment: @MarkBaker You're right. I am so dumb to not realizing this sooner. Thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you need boolean true or false for `$test` basicly you can do if statment

```
$test = filter_var("ftp://ftp.is.co.za.example.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt", FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
if($test !== false){
    $test = true;
}
```